# return array of results from select query php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to implement search suggestions for an app and need to search a database table that contains a list of users. I need the script to return an array of with the details of all the users that fit the criteria (i.e if the user searches 'Jo' it'll return users named 'John' 'Joe' etc.). I've had a go at doing this using parts of some of my other scripts but I can't get the `mysqli_fetch_array` method to work properly.

I'm using an `onTextChangedListener` to query the script every time the user types something, I believe this is the right way to go about doing it. I'll post my code below, if there's any more info needed just let me know.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(database details);

$name = $_POST["name"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT user_id, name, email FROM users WHERE name = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $name);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $name, $email);


$response = mysqli_fetch_array($statement, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Within android studio I'm getting the error: `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: JSteward  did you checked the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try changint the mysqli_fetch array for the following loop:

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
    $response[] = [
        "user_id" => $user_id,
        "name" => $name,
        "email" => $email,
    ]; //assign each data to response array
}
```